# How to detect a progam calling "OpenFile" and what the name/path of the file is?

Tags: file-io

I have a program (just exe) that is not able to OpenFile.

Its a log file to write to so I just need to place an empty file.

But I don't know the name or location of it, and have dug around the registry and ini and inf files to no avail.

Should I use a system hook?

Answer (score 0):

The [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) tool will let you see which files a program is using in real time.

Comment: Aye, i've tried using that.

The problem is that the program is trying to OpenFile, and it fails (the file is not present)

As its trying to open a log file, if I can provide a blank file, it will open it and write to it, but i don't know the name of it.